# the 'right way' to distribute an app using other libraries

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries

I wrote an app which uses `Boost`. The compiled and linked binary executable program is small, but I want to distribute the source code(it's a FOSS).

Because the `Boost` itself is very large, I can't distribute my app with it. I want the users to download/build `Boost` themselves. The problem is:

1. how could I know whether `Boost` have been installed on user's machine and where it is?
2. if user wants to indicate the path he installed `Boost`, where should I have he put the parameters?

Of course the `Boost` above can be replaced with any other library.

Answer (score 1):

To only distribute the relevant Boost libraries, you could use [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html). It will extract for you the required files, you can then include them in your project.